# Does "me encanto" translate to "I love me"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, verbos, definiciones, sintaxis

Since "encantar" somewhat means **"to be pleasing to (someone)"** (aka. someone loves something), can "me encanto" be translated as "I love me/myself" (lit. *I am pleasing to me*)?

Edit: Can yall stop freaking out over the possibly narcissistic implications of this question? I'm tryin to learn Spanish and I'm experimenting conjugating different verbs to see if they make sense! People are so sensitive!

Comment: Frankly, who would say that? I love myself is me quiero or me amo. Me encanto is I'm enchanting to myself.....just not said. Would you ever say that?

Comment: Maybe the expression was "me encantó" (I loved it)?

Comment: What is the context? That sentence does not make sense to me.

"Me encanto", as is, could be translated into "I love myself" or "I like myself", but it sounds like a little narcissistic, so I think your context is other. However, if you meant "me encantó", it could be translated as "I liked it very much"

Comment: Mc Donalds translate his label "I'm lovin' it" as "Me encanta". Just saying

Comment: Why is everybody trying to change this to me encantó? That is not the OP's question at all. Me encanto a mi mismo. = I am very pleased with myself. If you can even bear reading that.

Answer (score 1):

A better translation of "encantar" in that context is "charm" (remember that encantar can have a lot of different connotations ranging from "love" all the way to "cast a spell") so the phrase "me encanto" as in "me encanto a mí mismo" would be either "I charm myself" (which is kinda awkward) or "I find myself charming" (which sounds more natural).

Answer (score 0):

As a Spanish native I've never used "me encanto" to talk about myself. In my case, here in Spain, I usually use "Encantar" to talk about something I really like... For example "Me encanta jugar Golf" or "Me encantó la cena de ayer". If I want to talk about me I would use "Me quiero/Me amo/Me gusto".
Hope this helps.

Comment: As a native English speaker, we don't usually go around saying "I love myself" either.

Answer (score 0):

I mean, technically, you could use *me encanto* to say that you love something about you. At least in Mexico, it is very common.

For example, you could say:

> Soy muy intelligente, ¡me encanto!

Which would translate to

> I'm so smart, I love it!

Other examples of this type of construction could be:

> Me caigo muy bien o me caigo mal

Answer (score -1):

If the sentence is intended to describe something I really liked, such as "Me encantó la película" then it would be translated as "I loved the picture". An example using encantar in present tense could be "Me encanta la comida mexicana" to say "I love Mexican food".

This is generally the context in which encantar is used.

Comment: At the moment the OP has _encanto_, the first person present form not as you have stated.